# SQL JOIN 3 tables, unique rows, calculation across tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables. They have the same columns. I need to merge them into one table, such that I only have unique rows, the amount columns needs to be computed across the 3 tables.

e.g.

Table 1

Name1, 2, 100.00

Name5, 3, 25.00

---

Table 2

Name1, 2, 50.00

---

Table 3

Name1, 2, 60.00

---

Desired Result:

Name1, 2, 90.00 i.e. calculated as (100-60+50)

Name5, 3, 25.00

Any ideas? I've tried union but that doesn't calculate for me or show unique rows....

Comment: Your question is not very clear. How are the tables related and what values do you want to add?

Comment: What is the second column and how should it be combined across the three tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty clear question.  Use UNION ALL to combine the tables into one queryable thing, then use GROUP BY to combine rows that share a value.

```
SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) as Col2
FROM
(
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table3
) as sub
GROUP BY Col1
```

Answer (score 3):

In this solution, I simply took the Min value of the second column since you did not specify how it should be combined across the three tables.

```
Select Z.Name, Min( SomeInt ) As MinSomeInt
    , Sum( SomeDecimal ) As TotalSomeDecimal
From    (
        Select Name, SomeInt, SomeDecimal
        From Table1
        Union All
        Select Name, SomeInt, SomeDecimal
        From Table2
        Union All
        Select Name, SomeInt, SomeDecimal * -1
        From Table3
        ) As Z
Group By Z.Name
```

Comment: +1 My interpretation would have been to GROUP BY both Name and SomeInt.